# Error message on terminal despite using 2> symbol

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

Why does this command show error message despite using 2> symbol?

```
    cat < foo 2>bar
    bash : cannot open foo : No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `2>` is redirecting the standard error of `cat`.  `cat` is not being run however, because bash cannot open the file you specified as standard input to `cat`.  To get the behavior you want, use

```
(cat < foo) 2> bar
```

This will run `cat < foo` in a subshell and redirect the error output of bash to bar.  If you also want the error output from cat, you could do

```
(cat < foo 2> bar) 2> bar2
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Casey notes, putting the command in a subshell works:

```
$ ( cat <foo ) 2>bar
```

However, the subshell is not necessary.  A simple list works just as well:

```
$ { cat <foo ; } 2>bar
```

You don't even need the list if you observe that the order in which redirects are done makes a difference:

```
$ cat <foo 2>bar
bash: foo: No such file or directory
$ cat 2>bar <foo
```

My conclusion is that what matters is bash's processing order: the issue is whether stderr has been redirected *before* or *after* the moment when bash discovers that the redirect of stdin fails.  Thus, there is no output from the last example above because bash *first* redirects stderr and *then* tries to open foo for stdin.